# Perl inserts unwanted keys in hashes

Tags: macos, perl, hash

I keep having this problem with Perl and it's really getting annoying.

Platform: Mac OS X 10.7; Perl v5.12.3

Sample script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

undef %hash;

@letters = qw / a b c /;
@numbers = qw / 1 2 3 /;

for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){
    $hash{$letters[$i]}=$numbers[$i];
}

foreach $key (%hash) {
    print $key."\n";
}
```

For some scripts I get the first output (extra keys), sometimes I get the other (extra values)

Output:

```
a
a
b
b
c
c
```

or

```
1
2
3
a
b
c
```

Is this a 'feature' of Perl? How do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Quicker assignment using a hash slice: `@hash{@letters} = @numbers;`

Comment: Also, you're not getting that output with that code. You should not mix and match code and output, post the output that goes with the code.

Comment: It's not a feature, it's a bug in this case =).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the `keys` keyword to get the keys from the hash.

```
for my $key (keys %hash) {
    print $key."\n";
}
```

Otherwise, the hash gets flatted into a list, and returns all the keys and values.

Comment: THANKS! I feel like such an idiot. I usually put keys because I sort them but I didn't know about this 'feature' of making a hash into a list.

Comment: @IMPERATOR That is not a "feature", it is a core functionality of Perl. All variables when put in list context are expanded into a list of their elements. In fact, it applies to most functions as well.

Answer (score -1):

The answer that suggests using 'keys' is correct, i just wanted to remind you to always put
'use strict;' and 'use warnings;' at the beginning of your scripts.